# How can I list scheduled mails in mandrill?

Tags: email, mandrill, mailing

Hi I want to list all the emails that are scheduled but not send and I can't find that option. Is it posible?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

/messages/list-scheduled.json API lists upto 1000 scheduled emails.

API Result:

```
[{
    "_id": "I_dtFt2ZNPW5QD9-FaDU1A",
    "created_at": "2013-01-20 12:13:01",
    "send_at": "2021-01-05 12:42:01",
    "from_email": "sender@example.com",
    "to": "test.recipient@example.com",
    "subject": "This is a scheduled email"
}]
```

[More details](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=list-scheduled)